# Is it ok for my model to inherit from Controller class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I want to use the `Json` method of the Controller class so I can pass back a JsonResult to the Controller...like this (this is the method in my model class):

```
public JsonResult GetJsonResultByName(string collectionName)
    {
        JsonResult returnJsonResult = new JsonResult();

        switch (collectionName)
        {
            case "homeMyClientsProspectsGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(homeData.myClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "revenueMyRevenueGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(revenueData.myRevenueClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "revenueMyBacklogGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(revenueData.myBacklogClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "salesMyYTDSalesGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(salesData.myYTDSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "salesMyYTDCostOfSalesGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(salesData.myYTDCostOfSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "salesMyActiveOpportunitiesGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(salesData.myActiveOpportunityClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "projectsMyPTDProjectStatusGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(projectData.myPTDProjectStatusClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "projectsMyBillingsAndCollectionsGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(projectData.myBillingsAndCollectionsClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "projectsMyWorkInProcessGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(projectData.myWorkInProcessClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "burnMyLaborBurnRateGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(burnData.myLaborBurnRateClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
            case "burnMyLaborRevenueProjectionGrid":
                returnJsonResult = Json(burnData.myLaborRevenueProjectionClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                break;
        }

        return returnJsonResult;
    }
```

But to do this I need my model to inherit from Controller. Is this bad practice? Should I be doing this some other way?

Some background...Each of these is providing data to a grid/table on the webpage via an ajax call:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Data", "PortfolioManager")' + '?gridName=burnMyLaborRevenueProjectionGrid', function (data) {

                    ConstructburnMyLaborRevenueProjectionGrid(data);
                    $('#burnMyLaborRevenueProjectionLoadingIndicator').hide();
                    numGridsLoaded = numGridsLoaded + 1;
                });
```

It works like this (inheriting from Controller), but something feels *dirty* about it...

Comment: How does the controller look? The code you posted looks like it would fit perfectly  in the controller. The model shouldn't be responsible for returning JSON and stuff, instead the controller should return the model as JSON.

Comment: The controller is very sparse, just a few lines of code. It just calls `GetJsonResultByName(string collectionName)`. I was trying to make the controller as simple as possible. So you think that code should go in the Controller?